# iOS 8 CGContext errors when showing keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am running a very simple one page app compiled with iOS6 SDK with a UITextField on an iOS 8.0.2 device (iPad).
When tapping on the textfield and when the keyboard shows, a whole bunch of errors are printed on the console, mentioning an invalid CGContext:

> < Error >: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> < Error >: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
> error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
> context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
> system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
> fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: We need more context. Has your `UITextField` other siblings on view?